# Can we add multiple values for a single key in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

In gitlab can we define multiple values for a single key?

So gitalb->under cicd->variables.

I have a key called "Appname"  and I want to pass mutliple values as "app1,appe2,app3". Like

Key             Value
Appname         app1,app2,app3

Is this possible if so can you someone share documentation

Comment: CI/CD values can only be passed as strings or files, it's up to the script or app that reads the values to split them into multiple values (e.g. via loop or convert to array)

Comment: $myList = @("app1","app2","app3","app4")

My script is written in a way to follows above format but when I define similar format in my environment variables I am getting below error.

Error: The character length of the 46 argument is too long. Shorten the 
character length of the argument so it is fewer than or equal to "15" characters, and then try the command again.

Comment: If possible can you please share an example on how to define values in a file